# How can I store text file in MYSQL database using QT?

Tags: mysql, qt

I have a table which has two columns: ID, FILE;
The FILE column has BLOB type;
I want to store the full file in the database not the content of the file.
I would like to download the file later as file_name.txt

This is how I tried but after insert the FILE is NULL;

```
 query.exec("INSERT INTO test(ID, FILE) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('/home/nemeth/Documents/list.txt'));
```

Comment: Is the MySQL server local or remote?

Comment: The mysql server is local.

Answer (score 0):

According to 
[MySQL documentation on LOAD_FILE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file), the file must satisfy some conditions to be loaded. Not only being local but also permissions and stuff.

> LOAD_FILE(file_name)
>
> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this
>   function, the file must be located on the server host, you must
>   specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE
>   privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than
>   max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is
>   set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
>   located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the
>   preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.
>
> The character_set_filesystem system variable controls interpretation
>   of file names that are given as literal strings.

Also have you tried searching a little?... [Lookie here :p](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20LOAD_FILE)

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what is the problem so I solved differently.
I've read the file into a QByteArray and inserted the array into the database.

```
QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, FILE) VALUES (1,?)");
query.addBindValue(byteArray);
query.exec();
```